# Define Each New Line As a Variable

Tags: python

I have a text file that has many lines of data. I would like to setup a loop that reads each line of data and then defines that line/data as a new variable to be used in my python script.'

**File Example:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Python Script (so far...):**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('/home/weather/test', 'r')
for line in f.read().split('\n'):
    print line
f.close()
```

Comment: Ok, that part is looking good (but could be improved by using `for line in f.readlines()`). What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you want to have dynamically named variables, really you want a sequence or mapping. In your case, sequence (e.g. list) will be enough. List of lines may be retrieved from file by `.readlines` method.

```
with open('/home/weather/test', 'r'):
    all_lines = f.readlines()
print all_lines[0]  # first line
print all_lines[1]  # second line
print len(lines)  # lines count
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `List` and append the variables to it like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open('/home/weather/test', 'r')
variables=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    variables.append(line)
f.close()
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) is a good tutorial about lists

Answer (score 1):

Use `exec` with a string representing the required code:

```
for i in range(5):
    exec('line%d=%d'  % (i, i))

print(line0)
print(line1)
print(line2)
print(line3)
print(line4)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The `exec` line activates the python interpreter on the given string, so for example when i == 0 you get `exec("line0 = 0")`, and so `line0` pops into existance!

Comment: Where do I insert my text file path?